# Fixing a style sheet for IE 7 8 9

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css

I’m not sure if it’s acceptable to ask this kind of thing but since I have no idea how to solve it:

I created an HTML5 CSS3 layout from scratch and it looks exactly how I want in Firefox 5, Safari 5.1 and Chrome 12 for Mac.
But when I use https://browserlab.adobe.com/ for the same browsers, it appears a little broken (footer in the middle, background repeat, sub menus visible).
That made me wonder if I could trust Adobe’s tool or not.

Then when I use browserlab or http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ to view it in IE it’s totally broken (to be expected).
• In IE9 the radial background is missing, menus are not styled or rotated and thrown to the far right, main content appears below the sidebar and its width is not respected (strange because in an older version of my layout it displayed just fine in IE9)
• In IE8 some times it’s the same thing with sidebar list taking all the space, sometimes it’s just a black page.
• In IE7 if it’s not the black or white page, it’s worse than in IE8 with the main content being unreadable.

I use two JS, one that fixes many IE issues and the other that brings HTML5 tags support but they seem to conflict or at least to be responsible for the black pages.

I do hope that it in fact displays fine in mozilla and webkit. I’m worried about IE because I have no idea how to fix it and 13% of my visitors use it (not negligible).

I would greatly appreciate any help as this is blocking me from launching the site (which is already overdue).

http://protostype.free.fr/index-sitepointversion4.php

EDIT1: validated HTML, CSS gives errors, not sure anything can be done about it
EDIT2: fixed biggest layout problems, new link

Comment: There's too much stuff wrong on your page for this to be a viable question. Voting to close, sorry. The biggest problem in IE7/8 is that your html5shiv ("HTML5 tags support") script is not working, for whatever reason. If you make that work, things will be much better.

Comment: Try looking at some other polyfills/shims: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: @thirtydot what else is wrong ? actually if it's almost valid it can't be wrong. How do you know that html5shiv isn't working ?

Comment: @vonkly which other ? there's only one for for those tags and I'm using it.

Comment: The page being valid does not mean it will work in Internet Explorer, especially in older versions, which have many bugs. Looking at your page today in IE8 again, it just appears as solid white with nothing on the page. Yesterday, the page appeared but it was completely broken due to html5shiv not working. I could tell it wasn't working by pressing F12 to bring up the Developer Tools, and looking at the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as others have said, it seems that html5shiv isn't working properly for you. I had this same problem with html5shiv, and I could never work out why, but I found that replacing it with Modernizr did the trick for me (Modernizr includes the same functionality plus a bunch of other good stuff; see their site for more info).

That may well fix a lot of the issues.

Stuff like the radial background and `border-radius` on the tabs might be fixable using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com).

You're using `transparent` in your stylesheets. I'm fairly sure this isn't supported, at least in IE7 (not sure about IE8?). There are a number of work-arounds for IE to support stuff like this, but none of them are particularly great.

The position of your rotated menus is wrong because of differences in the way IE rotates elements compared with other browsers. IE's filter style uses a different point of origin for the rotation: it rotates around the top-left corner, whereas CSS3-compliant browsers default to rotating around the centre point.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the CSS3 `transform-origin` style to get the CSS3 browsers to act the same as IE (I'd prefer to change IE's origin point, but it's much more painful to change it in IE).

You're using CSS selectors like this:

```
.ul_nav_main li a:not(:last-child):after
```

That won't work in IE8. Neither `:not` nor `:last-child` are supported by IE8 or earlier, and `:after` isn't supported in IE7. You're also using some complex attribute selectors, which won't work in older IEs either.

I think that deals with most of the issues I could see. If you're still having problems once you've gone through all that lot, I'd suggest asking again (but make your question more specific next time! it'll be easier to answer)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx. Before you answered I think I was able to fix most problems (with external help) see new link. HTMLshiv should now work. I gave up modernizr because from what I understood it doesn't fix anything, only lets you know what's missing. I'm more concerned by layout issues than decoration issues. I dunno if IE9 supports border-radius, i don't see round corners in browserlab. I use PIE now for IE8-. It's trivial if pseudo class stuff doesn't work, but I use an IE fix and it appears to do the job. The thing I'm a bit worried about is the line breaks and line jumps, I use <pre> and pre-line

Comment: No worries. Hope I was able to help with at least something? :)  re Modernizr: you're right that it is mainly aimed at knowing what's missing so that you can adjust the site to suit, but it does also include the whole of HTML5Shiv, and I found it works better for me than HTML5Shiv did on its own (not sure why). Re border radius: IE9 does indeed support `border-radius`. You might find [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com) useful for questions like that.